# css float troubleshooting

Tags: html, css

i've got a very simple CSS example detailed below.   The .entry class generates a simple box with a 1px black border.   the example below, will render "123" within the box and "abc" and "xyz" outside the box because those elements are tagged with float left and right.  My goal is to have .box1 inside .entry aligned left, and .box2 inside .entry aligned right.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
        .entry 
    {
        width: 400px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000;
    }   
    .box1
    {
        width: 75px;
                float: left;
    }

    .box2
    {
        width: 300px;
                float: right;   
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="entry">
            123
            <div class="box1">abc</div>
            <div class="box2">xyz</div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it renders fine in IE but not firefox

Comment: Looks fine to me - does what I'd expect... perhaps some screenshots to see what you mean. I don't have IE on this computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since floats are taken out of the normal flow, their surrounding boxes will collapse.

I'll first explain why it is working in IE. You have given it "layout" by setting a width or height on each element. It's `width` in this case. See [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) for more about this. This is very handy as it will also solve most of any other IE bugs you come across.

The magic bullets are:

```
height: 1%; /* or any other value. IE6 wrongly sees height as min-height. */
```

or if you aren't in a position to set a specific size, use

```
zoom: 1; /* A IE only property. Doesn't validate, but doesn't cause any harm either */
```

So, to your problem, making it working in a proper browser, there are a couple of solutions. If you set the parent of the floated elements to have `float` as well, the box will stretch around the child floats. Although this might cause trouble further up the DOM, I don't know how the rest of your markup is.

An easier way can then be to set `overflow:hidden;` which also fixes it. But now you have to watch out for long url's, code-snippets, or anything else that might accidentally push out of the div. If you're doing the whole site yourself this is normally not a big problem, if you're handing it over to someone to use in a CMS, chances are slightly larger. Still worth taking the risk though, if you can't solve a myriad of floats around your layout.

Adding an element at the end to clear the floats is also a way of doing it, but I find the former ways easier.

I better stop blabbering, you probably want to see the code:

```
.entry {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;      /* Option 1 */
  overflow: hidden; /* Option 2 */
}   
.box1 {
  width: 75px;
  float: left;
 }
.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no Doctype, you are triggering [Quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html). This renders browsers significantly more buggy then Standards (AKA Strict) mode. Internet Explorer is the worst offender here.

I suspect your  problem is that you want the border of .entry to extend around .box1 and .box2. See [containing floats](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) for more detail and [Methods for Containing Floats](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59) for some nicer solutions..

Of course, your problem might be something different. [You were rather vague](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floats for FF:

```
.entry:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

I would do it for IE as well:

```
.entry { min-height: 10px;}
```

Otherwise, I don't see why it wouldn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Try this; I've tested it and it works in FF 3, Safari 3.2, Opera 9.6 and IE 7.

(The reason I added the extra line of text in the `.box2` div was to ensure that the `.entry` div would stretch vertically as extra content was added).

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .entry 
    {
        width: 400px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000;
    }   
    .box1
    {
        width: 75px;
        float: left;
    }

    .box2
    {
        width: 300px;
        float; left;
        margin: 0 0 0 75px;
    }

    .entry span
    {
        width: 400px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="entry">
            <span>123</span>
            <div class="box1">abc</div>
            <div class="box2">xyz<br>More text</div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding overflow:hidden (or auto) to .entry{...}